# Uncomputability of $a<b$ or $b<a$

Tags: computability

Is it possible to prove the existence of two real numbers $a, b$ that have the property that it is uncomputable whether or not $a<b$?

Comment: That depends on how you're allowing me to specify real numbers!

Comment: Is it cheating to let $a=1$, and $b=2$ if the continuum hypothesis is true, $b=0$ if not?

Comment: No, I think that's a brilliant solution!

Comment: Or? Does $b$ exist, Harald?

Comment: For a number to exist, shouldn't it be a specific number? If it is uncomputable whether b is 0 or 2, then it is not a specific number. The uncomputability should be if $a<b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot be proved, because no such numbers exist; that is, for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, the value of the function $f_{<}: {\Bbb{R}}^2\to\{0,1\}$ such that 
$$f_{<}(a,b) =
\begin{cases}
& 1 \ \ \text{ if }\ a < b\\
& 0 \ \ \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$ can be computed *for those particular $a$ and $b$*. This is so because, regardless of how the two reals are supposed to be represented as input, the following two programs exist: program $P_0$ does nothing but output $0$ and halt, and program $P_1$ does nothing but output $1$ and halt. Consequently, one of these two programs correctly computes the number $f_{<}(a,b)$. (That we may not *know which* of these two programs is the correct one is not relevant to its existence.)

However, note that in reasonable models of real computation, the function $f_{=}: {\Bbb{R}}^2\to\{0,1\}$ such that
$$f_{=}(a,b) = (1-f_{<}(a,b))(1-f_{<}(b,a)) = \begin{cases}
& 1 \ \ \text{ if }\ a = b\\
& 0 \ \ \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

is uncomputable (see a proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/40647/39454)), and hence *the function $f_{<}$ is uncomputable* -- in contrast to the computability of any single number such as $f_{<}(a,b)$.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong about what I am about to write in the following (I have no experience with computability other than reading a bit about it).

In my mind, the fact that we may not know which of $P_0$ and $P_1$ is the correct one, is exactly why we haven't computed anything. We don't know the answer. Information about the truth exists in the system of definitions, but this truth cannot reach the user, and by this, has not been computed.

How is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: This is a subtle point: computability may be proved *nonconstructively*, without any explicit description of a specific algorithm; rather, what's required is proof of the *existence* of the relevant algorithm. (This is also illustrated by the last two examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function#Examples .)

Comment: Aha! Thanks for clearing that up!. Anyway, nonconstructive computability feels like an oxymoron to me...

Comment: It isn't "nonconstructive computability", it's "nonconstructive *proof of* computability".